# current-menu-item class not working properly

Tags: menus, hooks

I am using same term multiple time in my menu and when one term is active all occurrence of this term are assigned with `current-menu-item` class.
Actually I am getting menu id when that specific term is assigned with `current-menu-item` class.

But I always get id of its first occurrence. So how I can remove this class from other instances of this term so I can get a correct menu id?

Comment: I'm over simplifying a little bit, but WordPress is applying `current-menu-item` to all menu items with identical objects that are connected to the page you are viewing. Which definitely makes sense in a way, because generally you want to identify the element you are viewing, not the menu item you clicked. So I hate to break it to you, but I'm pretty sure it is indeed working properly and as intended. 

Otherwise I would advice you to add detailed information.

Comment: @Nicolai Thank you so much for your time and help. I just want to get current menu id and if you want more detail then you can read this from here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/284986/terms-with-more-than-one-occurrence-have-current-menu-item-class-in-menu

Comment: I am in this problem for few days but not able to find out solution for this.

Comment: Are you working with taxonomies, pages? Or what are you referring to, when your speaking about terms?

Comment: I have four custom taxonomies and all these are assigned with lot of terms. I am using few of these terms in multiple places and i have three level menu. I have AND condition in my tax_query among menu item and its parent menus. I am getting menu id correctly with that code but when there are multiple occurrence of this term it always return id of first occurrence and it is because of current-menu-item class.

Comment: You're just getting the first id, because the code in your other question is breaking after the first occurrence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68337/discussion-between-nicolai-and-muhammad-bilal).